# smooth fade out gone when i remove my mouse over the link

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I used a :hover transition on my blog theme. When i hover on it, it's smooth but when i remove the mouse, the fade out transition is not smooth anymore. Here is my code:

```
a.lo{
text-decoration: none;
border-top: none;
letter-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;}

a.lo:hover{
color:#fff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
background: none;
border-top: none;
padding-bottom: 16px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;}
```

my blog is [here](http://melancholia-themes.tumblr.com/) (it's the links on the upper right)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your unhovered class -

```
a.lo {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent; 
}
```

This is because the unhovered state needs something to transition from, your current code there's nothing so the CSS is snapping back to the beginning.

[Here's a JSFiddle that you can go off of.](http://jsfiddle.net/7qa8szj5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not transitioning when you remove the mouse is because you have it set to add the border bottom on hover, rather than transition the color. You can make it transition in and out by adding the following attribute:

`a.lo {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}`

That way when you mouse over, it's transitioning the color of the border bottom, rather than adding it.

Answer (score 0):

for transition add an animate class to the element you want the transition

```
.animate 
 { 
  transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
 }
```

Now when you add this class to your element it will make transition in both hover and hover out.